# Ruby on Rails - integrate existent project - where to put css/js files and call them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have downloaded [AdminLTE Bootstrap theme](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) and modified it to my needs. As separated pages they work well. Here is the structure of working sample:

```
├───homepage.html
├───dashboard.html
├───(... other html pages)
├───bower_components                                 
│   ├───bootstrap                                    
│   │   ├───dist                                     
│   │   │   ├───css                                  
│   │   │   ├───fonts                                
│   │   │   └───js                                   
│   │   ├───fonts                                    
│   │   ├───grunt                                    
│   │   ├───js                                       
│   │   ├───less                                     
│   │   │   └───mixins                               
│   │   └───nuget                                    
│   ├───bootstrap-datepicker                         
│   │   ├───.github                                  
│   │   ├───build                                    
│   │   ├───dist                                     
│   │   │   ├───css                                  
... other bootstrap components, which I will use. 
│   ├───Ionicons                                     
│   │   ├───css                                      
│   │   ├───fonts                                    
│   │   ├───less                                     
│   │   ├───png                                      
│   │   │   └───512                                  
│   │   ├───scss                                     
│   │   └───src                                      
│   ├───jquery                                       
│   │   ├───dist                                     
│   │   ├───external                                 
│   │   │   └───sizzle                               
│   │   │       └───dist                             
│   │   └───src                                      
│   │       ├───ajax                                 
│   │       │   └───var                              
...
│   └───select2                                      
│       ├───.github                                  
│       ├───dist                                     
│       │   ├───css                                  
│       │   └───js                                   
│       │       └───i18n                             
│       ├───docs                                     
│       ├───src                                      
├───dist                   # AdminLTE native css, img and js                          
│   ├───css                                          
│   │   ├───alt                                      
│   │   └───skins                                    
│   ├───img                                          
│   │   └───credit                                   
│   └───js                                           
│       └───pages                                    
└───plugins                  # other plugins I may use                        
    ├───bootstrap-slider                             
    ├───bootstrap-wysihtml5                                                        
    ├───input-mask                                   
    │   └───phone-codes                              
    ├───jQueryUI                                     
    ├───jvectormap                                   
    ├───pace                                         
    └───timepicker
```

Roughly, I have `bower_componets`, `dist` and `plugins` where AdminLTE puts css/js files, and my modified html pages in dir root. I have changed the image/css/js paths to be relative, and it's working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
```

But, in Ruby on Rails, I am told to put all css files into `app/assets/stylesheets/` and all js files into `app/assets/javascripts/`, to compile a whole file to use. I put all pages in `public/static_pages`, and when I run the server, the pages render, but no css, no js are found, due to relative path hard-coded in html.

My question:

Is there a simpler way to integrate my project in Rails way, in order not to change this dir structure? Reorganize all these is a time-consuming task, and what I want is a simple demo, static type. I am still learning and wonder if I can bind data in rail way while organizing resources in static way.

I am using Rails 5.1.

PS:

Should the css/js files be put into `vendor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:

1. Put all necessary js/css into `app/assets`
2. Precompile them by adding each one into the precompile array(`config/initializers/assets.rb`).

It equals to:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( _all-skins.css AdminLTE.css bootstrap.css font-awesome.css ionicons.css)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( adminlte.js bootstrap.js demo.js home_js.js)
```

3. No need to touch `application.js`, `application.css`. `//require_tree .` has done all.
4. Comment out all `<stylesheet>` and `<script>` lines where in the page these files are used. They are obsolete.
5. Use them in `app/views/layouts/application.html.rb`:

That is to say:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<!-- AdminLTE specific css -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'AdminLTE', 'bootstrap', '_all-skins', 'font-awesome', 'ionicons' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<!-- AdminLTE specific js -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'adminlte', 'bootstrap', 'demo' %>
<!-- real external js -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic" %>
```

6. Page-specific scripts should be included in separated files, like my `homepage` has `home_js.js`; create another file, put it into `app/assets/javascripts`, include it into the precompile array, but use it *not* in `application.html.erb`, but in the real content page `pages/homepage.html.erb`: `<%= javascript_include_tag "home_js" %>`. By that, you cannot prevent extra precompile work, but you just use them in one page, not in all.

I know there are better solutions, because by this mean I must identify very clear which page uses which scripts/css, and add only the used-by-all-pages ones into `application.html.rb` to prevent load unnecessary resources, but at least it is running. Any improvement is welcome.